# Create file in LXC container with Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, lxc

I have a playbook:

```
- hosts: Server-52
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 

    - name: Run a command in a container
      lxc_container:
        name: Jitsi
        container_log: true
        state: started
        container_command: |
          touch FUFUFU.txt
```

This playbook must to create a file `FUFUFU.txt` in my LXC container `Jitsi`

My container:

```
root@devel-lxd01:/etc/keepalived# lxc list
+----------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|   NAME   |  STATE  | IPV4 | IPV6 |   TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |  LOCATION   |
+----------+---------+------+------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| Jitsi    | RUNNING |      |      | CONTAINER | 0         | devel-lxd01 |
```

But when I tried deploy this playbook, I get error:

```
PLAY [Server-52] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Run a command in a container] ****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [Server-52]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to find required executable \"lxc-create\" in paths: /root/.vscode-server/bin/3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316/bin:/root/.vscode-server/bin/3a6960b964327f0e3882ce18fcebd07ed191b316/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************
Server-52                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Could you please tell me where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using lx**d** rather than lx**c** to run your containers.
Try using the module `lxd_container` rather than `lxc_container`, for your task.